# Passing form ID's as a variable back and forth between javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let me start off by saying while I'm pretty good with PHP and HTML, I don't know much about javascript/jquery. I also apologize if this has been answered before, but I haven't had much luck finding anything in the search.

I'm working on a project where we have a form of undetermined size that I want to build some autocomplete functionality into. The form fields and necessary div's are being named using a counter as you can see in the code below.

```
$set_b = 'upl_band'.$count;
$sugbox = $set_b."sug";
$autobox = $set_b."auto";
echo "<div><input type=text name='$set_b' size=25 id='$set_b' onkeyup='bandlookup(this.value,'$set_b');' onblur='bandfill();'></div>";
echo "<div class='suggestionsBox' id='$sugbox' style='display: none;'><img src='upArrow.png' style='position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;' alt='upArrow' /><div class='suggestionList' id='$autobox'>&nbsp;</div></div>";
```

I'm trying to pass the main value - $set_b into my javascript onkeyup. However, somewhere along the line I'm losing my values. If I setup my form with concrete id's this code works fine, but when I make my id's variable I'm getting lost. My javascript is below. The post call to band.php is my lookup script.

```
function bandlookup(bandString, boxName) {
    if(bandString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        var s = boxName+"sug";
        $("#"+s).hide();
    } else {
        var su = boxName+"sug";
        var suauto = boxName+"auto";
        $.post("band.php", {queryString: ""+bandString+"", inputName: ""+boxName+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $("#"+su).show();
                $("#"+suauto).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function bandfill(thisValue, boxName) {
    var s = boxName+"sug";
    $("#"+boxName).val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#'+s).hide();", 200);
}
```

and band.php

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');

if(!$db) {
    // Show error if we cannot connect.
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {
    // Is there a posted query string?
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        $box = $_POST['inputName'];
        // Is the string length greater than 0?

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
                $query = $db->query("SELECT band_name,band_id FROM upl_band WHERE band_name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
                if($query) {
                    // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object (i like PHP5 btw!).
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        // Format the results, im using <li> for the list, you can change it.
                        // The onClick function fills the textbox with the result.
                        echo '<li onClick="bandfill(\''.$result->band_name.'\',\''.$box.'\');">'.$result->band_name.'</li>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
                }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
```

My problem could be with the post call in the javascript, but I'm more leaning towards me improperly dealing with the variable variable names as an id tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is broken, try this:

```
echo "<div><input type=text name='$set_b' size=25 id='$set_b' onkeyup=\"bandlookup(this.value,'$set_b');\" onblur='bandfill();'></div>";
```